# What is the difference in meaning between "come with someone" and "come along with someone"?

Tags: prepositions, difference, phrase-choice

Is there any difference in meaning between the following sentences?

> Why don't you **come with** us to the party.
>
> Why don't you **come along with** us to the party.

I cannot see any difference, but I feel there is a small one because why would anyone add *along*.

Comment: The phrase _come along_ can mean to go with someone. "We're going to a party - would you like to come along?" In your example, because _with us_ follows, it doesn't really affect the meaning whether _along_ is included or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you "come with" somebody, it can mean that you brought them, or that they brought you.

"Come along with" means that you went with someone who was already going. See also '[tag along](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/tag-along)'.

In your examples which are posed as questions, it is possible they could mean the same thing - the context would determine that. However, the first could be an invitation from two people invited to the same party to just *travel* together, whereas the second sounds more like the first person is *inviting* someone else to come to the party.